# Sending an email via PHP and jquery/ajax from a html page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a very simple question but its been bugging me for quite some time .I have a html contact us page in which I have a simple form which already has validation assigned to it.The form code is :

```
    <div class="contact_form">      
  <form method="post" id="contactForm" name="contactForm" action="">
                    <fieldset class="contactFieldset">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <label for="contactName" class="leftLabel">*Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="contactName" id="contactName" class="contactInput required" value="" />

                            </li>
                            <p></p>
                            <li>
                                <label for="email" class="leftLabel">*Email:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="contactInput email required" value="" />
                            </li>
                          <span class="simple-success">I'll be in  touch soon</span>
                            <li>
                                <label for="subject" class="leftLabel">*Subject:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="contactInput required" value="" />
                            </li>
                            <p></p>
                            <li>
                                <label for="message" class="leftLabel">*Message:</label>
                                <textarea rows="10" cols="40" id="message" name="message" class="contactTextarea required"></textarea>

                            </li>
                           <p></p>
                            <li>


                                <input type="submit" alt="Submit button" name="submit" class="submit" id="submit">

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>


</div>
```

The code which I am using to try and call the php form using ajax is this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //if submit button is clicked
    $('#submit').click(function () { 

 alert("test i am here");



        /*get the email value*/

        var email = $("input#email").val();
        var name = $("input#contactName").val();
        var subject = $("input#subject").val();
        var message=$("input#message").val();
        alert("email"+email);

/* Check if the email is good or bad */

var goodEmail = email.match(/\b(^(\S+@).+((\.com)|(\.net)|(\.edu)|(\.mil)|(\.gov)|(\.org)|(\.info)|(\.sex)|(\.biz)|(\.aero)|(\.coop)|(\.museum)|(\.name)|(\.pro)|(\.arpa)|(\.asia)|(\.cat)|(\.int)|(\.jobs)|(\.tel)|(\.travel)|(\.xxx)|(\..{2,2}))$)\b/gi);
    apos=email.indexOf("@");dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");lastpos=email.length-1;
    var badEmail    = (apos<1 || dotpos-apos<2 || lastpos-dotpos<2);

/*If the email is bad ,display the error message*/

if (email=="" || !goodEmail || badEmail) {

        $("email").focus();
      return false;
    }


        var dataString = 'email='+ email + '\n Name='+ name+ '\n Subject='+ subject+ '\n message='+ message;
        alert (dataString);

        $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "mai.php",

      data: dataString,
      //Do not cache the page
            cache: false,
      success: function(html) {
        $('.simple-sucess').fadeIn(100).show();
        $('.contact_form').fadeOut(100).hide();
        $('.simple_error').fadeOut(100).hide();


      }
     });
    return false;
    });
});
```

The thing is the alert is not even being displayed when I press the submit button..what am I doing wrong here?

The validation code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $("#contactForm").validate();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use the [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event, not the submit button [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event because the submit button is already wired up to do a normal submit. There may also be a bug, be sure to check your javascript console for errors. Either way...

What you probably really want to do is use the [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) which will make your code a lot more simple.

Then your revised code would be as simple as:

```
$('#contactForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
            $('.simple-sucess').fadeIn(100).show();
            $('.contact_form').fadeOut(100).hide();
            $('.simple_error').fadeOut(100).hide()
        });
```

In this case you would lose your email validation, but why reinvent the wheel, there are [tons](http://speckyboy.com/2010/06/22/50-jquery-plugins-for-form-functionality-validation-security-and-customisation/) of validators out there that already have the bugs worked out etc.

Comment: Thanks,but wont I need to make a php call within the submit event ? The validation I am using is external i.e. using the jquery validation plugin.I'll update the code to show the validation code I am using

Comment: @MFrank2012 the jquery forms plugin will actually handle all the ajax stuff in that case. As for validation, I only saw the email validation where you used regexes to check it was valid. Maybe handle email validation in your validation plugin.

Comment: Read up on the jquery form plugin here http://jquery.malsup.com/form/ it will encapsulate all your ajax code and building your post data. The way you are building your datastring could run into problems, for example if I put a `=` in the name field.

Answer (score 0):

the first thing is you are using :

```
<input type="submit" alt="Submit button" name="submit" class="submit" id="submit">
```

in your form, and in jquery you are using `.click()` event,

if try to change

`<input type="submit" alt="Submit button" name="submit" class="submit" id="submit">`

to :

```
<input type="button" alt="Submit button" name="submit" class="submit" id="submit">
```

then it will work perfectly with the `.click()` event
or the second option you have if you don't want to change the input type then use `.submit()` instead of `.click()`

Answer (score 0):

OMG, so many code lines. A little suggestion: keep it simple enough to debug. A jsfiddle demo is recommended for better answers.

Here I post my solution for ajax forms, which works in basic browsers without javascript support.

html:

```
<form method="post" id="contactForm" action="somewhere">
    Name: <input type="text" name="contactName" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit this form" />
</form>
```

javascript:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#contactForm').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault?e.preventDefault():false;
        $.post(this.action,$(this).serialize(),function(text){
            //callbacks
            console.log(text);
        });
        return false;
    })
});
```